# Getting an assignment from incompatible pointer type error in C

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers

I have to make a code that declares and initalizes three variables, a double, int, and string (5 bits including null char) then print the size address, and value using printf and sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int number = 5, *pI;
    pI = &number; // Assigning Integer variable to integer pointer
    double number2 = 10.5, *pD;
    pD = &number2; // Assigning Double variable to Double pointer
    char arry[] = "dogs", *pc;
    pc = &arry; // Assigning Char Array variable to Char Array Pointer

    // Size, Address and Value stored in each Integer Variable, Double Variable and Character Variable
    printf("Integer Size is = %d , Address is = 0x%p and Value is = %d: \n",
            sizeof(number), &number, number);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("Double Size is = %d, Address is = 0x%p and Value is = %lf: \n",
            sizeof(number2), &number2, number2);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf(
            "Character Array Size is = %d, Address is = 0x%p and Value is = %s: \n",
            sizeof(arry), &arry, arry);
    fflush(stdout);

    // Pointers Size, Address and Value stored in each Integer Pointer, Double Pointer and Charecter pointer
    printf(
            "Pointer Integer Size is = %d , Address is = 0x%p and Value is = %d: \n",
            sizeof(pI), &pI, *pI);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf(
            "Pointer Double Size is = %d, Address is = 0x%p and Value is = %lf: \n",
            sizeof(pD), &pD, *pD);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf(
            "Pointer Character Array Size is = %d, Address is = 0x%p and Value is = %s: \n",
            sizeof(pc), &pc, pc);
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pc = &arry;` -> `pc = arry;`. Also you should use the correct identifiers in `printf`.

Comment: So I don't need to use the ampersand? Thank you btw!

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve, but the array name decays to a pointer to its first element in most cases (except `&`, `sizeof`, `alignof`). In your code the `&` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
char arry[] = "dogs", *pc;
pc = &arry;
```

`arry` is of type `char[5]`, it is an array of `char`, therefore `&arry` is a pointer to and array of `char`. Since `pc` is of type `char *` the pointers are incompatible.

```
pc = arry;
```

Here `arry` decays to a pointer to its first element, and this assignment is valid.

On the other side if you really want a pointer to a `char` array, as written in your comments, you have to declare it like this:

```
char (*pc)[5];
```

Also you should use the proper identifiers in `printf` and cast the pointers to `void *`. For `size_t` you should use `%zu`.